# How to "Dock" a UIToolbar to the bottom of the screen in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitoolbar

I have a UIToolbar that I added to a UITableViewController in my Storyboard.

[image: Toolbar Location]

When this view is displayed, the toolbar will show itself directly below the last item in my UITableView. I want to "Dock" my toolbar on the bottom of the screen. I want it to display in the same place every time rather than move around depending on a variable number of table cells in my view. I need the user to be able to see all the cells as well (It can't be covering UITableView items, UITableView needs to decrease its allotted display space). How can I do this?

Edit: Using a UINavigationController to handle my views

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a couple of options. The first and easiest of the two would be to use a `UITableViewController` embedded inside a `UINavigationController`, with the navigation controllers `toolbarHidden` property set to `NO`.

The other option is to use a `UIViewController`. A view controller has a `UIView` build in, and you can manually add and position a `UITableView` and a `UIToolbar` on it in this configuration. Both of these configurations will achieve your desired end result.

Comment: I set toolbarHidden to "NO" on my storyboard, moved my buttons down to the toolbar, and then deleted my old toolbar. Also set bar style to "UIBarStyleBlackOpaque" and setToolBarHidden: "NO" in viewDidLoad and "YES" in all segues out of this view. It all came down to using my UINavigationController toolbar. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!